# Check if a user is part of a specific group using Azure B2C claims

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

One of my project where we are displaying the group claims from Azure AD is failing because the user is part of a huge number of groups. Is there a way to check if the logged in user is part of a specific group and dispaly / filter the group claim to show only specific groups?

Comment: Hi did you check my answer? If it's helpful, you can mark it accepted. Thank you. If you have any further concern, please let me know.

Comment: Hi, I want to achieve this using identity experience framework policies and want to check if a user belongs to a particular group.

Comment: I know that you want to use custom policy. You need to create a REST function to retrieve a user’s group memberships using Graph API. See reference here: https://mrochon.azurewebsites.net/2019/05/06/using-groups-in-azure-ad-b2c/. As I suggested in my answer you need to filter with id directly with Graph API or filter with group name in your own code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Microsoft Graph API to get the group claim, you can filter with the group id like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user id}/memberOf?$filter=id eq '{group id}'
```

Obviously this requires you to know the group id in advance. Group name is not supported to filter.

You can also get all the groups by `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user id}/memberOf` and filter the group name in your own code. Then return the filter result to the group claim.